# awk replace in multiple columns specific character with one command

Tags: awk

Input (a.txt)

```
aa <tab> c-c-c<tab>k-k-k<tab>
ll <tab> j-j-j <tab>v-v-v<tab>
```

Needed output (b.txt)

```
aa <tab> c.c.c<tab> k.k.k<tab>
ll <tab> j.j.j <tab>v.v.v<tab>
```

Please correct me: (this does not work, works only if I ask to replace in $11 column)

```
awk -F "\t" -v OFS="\t" '{gsub("-",".",$11,&14,&17); print;}' /home/a.txt > /home/b.txt
```

Comment: i don't know where comes the field 11,14,17.

Comment: @AvinashRaj OP just want to do replacement on those 3 columns.

Comment: So is it important to retain the specific `<space><tab><space>`, `<tab><space>` and `<space><tab>` white space between fields as you show or can all field-separating white space be replaced with, say, a single tab character? The former is difficult, the latter is trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that you don't want to do the replacement on whole line, just 3 columns, then just do this:

```
awk -F "\t" -v OFS="\t" 'BEGIN{a[11]=a[14]=a[17]=7}
                      {for(x in a)gsub("-",".",$x)}7' /home/a.txt > /home/b.txt
```

Comment: Don't need the `=7` i don't think, `BEGIN{a[11];a[14];a[17]}` would suffice.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify the field number in gsub function if you want to do a global substitution on all the fields.

```
awk '{gsub(/-/,".")}1' /home/a.txt > /home/b.txt
```